# How to use Except method in list in c#

Tags: c#, .net, list, ienumerable

I had create a two int type list and assign the items that are only in list1 to list1 using except method. for eg

```
List<int> list1 = new List<int>();
List<int> list2 = new List<int>();

list1 = {1,2,3,4,5,6} // get items from the database
list2 = {3,5,6,7,8}   // get items from the database

list1 = list1.Except(list2); // gives me an error.
```

Please give me suggestion. What is the right way to do it.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

The `Except` method returns `IEnumerable`, you need to convert the result to list:

```
list1 = list1.Except(list2).ToList();
```

Here's a complete example:

```
List<String> origItems = new List<String>();
    origItems.Add("abc");
    origItems.Add("def");
    origItems.Add("ghi");
    
    List<String> newItems = new List<String>();
    newItems.Add("abc");
    newItems.Add("def");
    newItems.Add("super");
    newItems.Add("extra");
    
    List<String> itemsOnlyInNew = newItems.Except(origItems).ToList();
    foreach (String s in itemsOnlyInNew){
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
```

Since the only items which don't exist in the origItems are *super* & *extra*, The result output is :

> super
>
> extra

Comment: Can we use this for list of objects?

Comment: Yes. Take a look at examples in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=net-5.0